# How do you define a Taylor (or any kind of series) solution for a given functional equation?

Tags: functional-analysis

I don't specialize in functional analysis, but I remember seeing in differential equations that it is possible to derive a general taylor series (or some manipulation of it) solution to a differential equation. How would one go about doing the same for a functional equation?

Let's say you have $f(1/x)=-f(x)$, classic logarithm right? But how do you derive that just from that functional equation?

Comment: You can't derive it from the functional equation.  Obviously, $g(x)=0, x>0$ is a solution to the functional equation, as is $$g(x)=\cases{-1,&0<x<1\\0,&x=1\\1,&x>1}$$

Comment: I am not sure if you mistake functional analysis with the solution techniques for functional equations. I would have a look at a book on the later.

Comment: Well, can you derive anything from a functional equation that will tell you the function? Or is there some supplemental information that allows a series to be derived from a functional equation?